# Simulating marry in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo I am simulating a population and I want that individuals between 16 and 50 years old marry randomly with another single individual from the population. Each individual has an household-id and I want that the male individual change its household-id to his "wife" household id, but i don't know how to do it. For now I have this code

```
ask individuals [
  if not married? and sex = "male" and age >= 16 and age <= 50 [ 
    let potential-mate one-of individuals with [
      not married? and age >= 16 and age <= 50
      and sex = "female" and household-id != household-id
    ]
    if potential-mate != nobody [
      ; this command do an Bernoulli equation,
      ; the relation is based on empirical data i have
      ifelse random-bernoulli (- 0.765 * ln age + 2.9753) [
        stop
      ] [
        set my-mate potential-mate            
        set married? true            
        ask my-mate [ set married? true ]            
        ask my-mate [ set my-mate myself ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: If you could edit the question so the code is formatted a little better that would help people understand it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Have a look at the example in the dictionary entry for [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/myself.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke C's comment is correct: what you need is [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/myself.html), as in:

```
household-id != [ household-id ] of myself
```

That being said, I would strongly suggest modelling things like marriages as [links](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links). Here is a working example:

```
breed [individuals individual]
individuals-own [age sex household-id]

undirected-link-breed [marriages marriage]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-individuals 100 [
    set age random 100
    set sex one-of  ["male" "female"]
    set household-id random 100
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  marry-individuals
  reset-ticks
end

to marry-individuals
  let bachelors individuals with [ not married? and age >= 16 and age <= 50 ]
  ask bachelors with [ sex = "male" ] [
    let potential-mates bachelors with [
      sex = "female" and household-id != [ household-id ] of myself 
    ]
    if any? potential-mates [
      if not random-bernoulli (- 0.765 * ln age + 2.9753) [
        let mate one-of potential-mates
        create-marriage-with mate
        set household-id [ household-id ] of mate
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to-report married? ; individual reporter
  report any? my-marriages
end

to-report my-mate ; individual reporter
  report [ other-end ] of one-of my-marriages
end
```

This way, you don't have to manage separate variables for `married?` and `my-mate`: a single link tells you all need to know about the relationship between these two individuals. The main advantage is that it's much less error prone: there is no risk for the values of these variables to ever become inconsistent. Notice, also, how the `married?` and `my-mate` make these concepts just as easy to access as they were before.

Another couple of comments about your code:

- I usually avoid using [`stop`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/stop.html) if possible. The behavior of that primitive is not always intuitive, and it sometimes leads to errors.
- Notice how I create a temporary `bachelors` agentset. This avoids checking for the `age` and `married?` conditions twice and makes the code more readable.
- I don't know what you plan to do with them, but you might want to consider making `households` agents and representing membership in an household by creating a link to it. Using "id" numbers is not a very netlogoish way of doing things and sometimes lead to inefficient code.

Comment: Thanks all three for the comments. I knew about the myself but I didn't think on how i could use in this ocasion. 
Thanks Nicolas for the tip of using link, I think it will be better too, I will try to change the code so it works like this.
And about the households, they are actually agents and the individuals are hatched from them. But i will consider doing this as links too. I am knew programming and using netlogo so many times I don't do the most efficient code! So thank you very much for the help